# Java Client for Avaya IVR and CTI integration

Tags: java, ivr, avaya

I am looking to develop a Java client for integrating the Avaya IVR to CTI. I have two questions.

1. What is the format of the IVR output? How can this be read using JAVA? 
   I want to develop a java program that is able to the read the input caller feeds to the IVR and take some action based on that. 
   Are there some APIs or Webservices from Avaya that can be used for this purpose? If someone could provide me some links to websites where i can find API details for the said functionality, i would be grateful.
2. How do we configure the IVR to perform certain actions based on different inputs fed in by the caller?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment (IVR version, how it is integrated to Telephony Switch...)?

Answer (score 1):

If the Avaya IVR in question is the experience portal suite, interaction with the IVR is based on VXML and CCXML. Avaya provides the Orchestration Designer (OD) IDE (which is basically a set op Eclipse plugins), with a Java framework (called SCE, for Service Creation Environment) used for developing and interacting with the IVR applications.

The IVR applications developed using OD are installed as servlets on application servers like Tomcat. The application then "outputs" the VXML which are interpreted by the IVR system and rendered into voice, and accepts the feedback from the telephony system and feeds it as input into the IVR application. Since the application is written in Java, you can do practically anything you want using Java.

A typical workflow would be something like this:

1. Call comes into the IVR system
2. The IVR requests the start page of the IVR application
3. The IVR application is typically a Java servlet, doing some processing depending on the input parameters, and generates a VXML page
4. The IVR system renders this VXML into what the caller hears. The caller makes some input (account nr for example)
5. The IVR Application (servlet on Tomcat), takes the callers response as input. The Avaya Orchestration Designer Java framework provides you with all the classes required to extract the input from the caller.
6. The IVR Application can now verify the response received from the caller against backend systems.
7. Depending on the results, a new VXML page is generated.

It is important to note that the IVR system is just a "renderer". The IVR scripting is not done in the IVR system. The IVR "Application" performs this functionality. You can, in the one way or the other, compare it to a web browser requesting a page, and then renders the HTML into a nicely formatted web page.

You do not need to make use of Orchestration Designer specifically, but that is the official environment supported by Avaya. The VXML can be crafted by hand (or any other framework) and might work just as well.

You asked for a link with details, here it is: https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_orchestration_designer/overview/index.gsp
You can register on Avaya DevConnect for free and download the SDK's and documentation from there.

Answer (score 0):

We have developed a ivr server tool which i think is suitable in your environment. It has restful interface so you can integrate the server by development language like java. The link is http://upinget.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/ctisvr/